# QT QstandardItem issue

Tags: c++, qt

I'm wondering when declaring:

```
QStandardItem *baseItem = new QStandardItem("Hello");
```

How can I get the text I name text I give it (e.g. Hello) later on. For example I'd quite to compare the name I give it with a QString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`QStandardItem`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qstandarditem.html#text) documentation. `text()` returns what you want :

> Returns the item's text. This is the text that's presented to the user
>   in a view.

So for comparing it with a QString you just do :

```
if (baseItem->text() == anotherString)
   // do something
```

Comment: I swear I looked and couldn't find that! cheers I'll give that a try.